# Boost test fails with enum classes inside namespaces

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, operator-keyword, enum-class

If you define an `operator <<` for a C++11 `enum class`, then you can use it successfully with Boost's unit test library.

However if you put the `enum class` inside a `namespace`, the Boost code no longer compiles.

Why does putting the `enum class` inside a `namespace` stop it from working?  It works fine with `std::cout` both ways so surely this means the `operator <<` is correct?

Here is some sample code demonstrating the issue:

```cpp
// g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework
#include <iostream>
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE EnumExample
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

// Remove this namespace (and every "A::") and the code will compile
namespace A {

enum class Example {
    One,
    Two,
};

} // namespace A

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& s, A::Example e)
{
    switch (e) {
        case A::Example::One: s << "Example::One"; break;
        case A::Example::Two: s << "Example::Two"; break;
    }
    return s;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(enum_example)
{
    A::Example a = A::Example::One;
    A::Example b = A::Example::Two;

    // The following line works with or without the namespace
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    // The following line does not work with the namespace - why?
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the operator inside the namespace if you want to make use of [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

```
#include <iostream>
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE EnumExample
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

namespace A {

enum class Example {
    One,
    Two,
};


std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& s, Example e)
{
    switch (e) {
        case A::Example::One: s << "Example::One"; break;
        case A::Example::Two: s << "Example::Two"; break;
    }
    return s;
}

} // namespace A

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(enum_example)
{
    A::Example a = A::Example::One;
    A::Example b = A::Example::Two;

    // The following line works with or without the namespace
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    // The following line does not work with the namespace - why?
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Aha, that explains it, thanks!  Since I was declaring the function in a `.hpp` file, I had to put `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& s, Example e);` in the `.hpp` inside the namespace, then in the `.cpp` implementation, put it as `std::ostream& A::operator<< (std::ostream& s, A::Example e)` so it could be implemented outside the namespace.  Putting the `.cpp` implementation inside another `namespace A { }` clause doesn't work.

Comment: @Malvineous It's good practice to use fully qualified names when defining stuff anyway, if you mess up the declarations it'll give you an early error during compilation rather than linking.